# Setting up La Clojure with LWJGL

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, lwjgl

After having set up La Clojure/IntelliJ i tried to set up LWJGL as well.

After downloading/unzipping LWJGL I added lwjgl.jar and lwjgl_util.jar to the libraries under 'file -> project structure'.

Then i went to the console/repl and tried to import the classes required to implement the [basic example](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_IntelliJ_IDEA) listed on the lwjgl homepage. However i was only partially successful; here are my results:

```
user=> (import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException)
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
user=> (import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display)
UnsatisfiedLinkError no lwjgl in java.library.path  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary (ClassLoader.java:1860)
```

Why is it possible to import 'org.lwjgl.LWJGLException' but not 'org.lwjgl.opengl.Display'? Or did I maybe misinterpret the REPL output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LWJGL is a bit trickier than other (pure Java) libraries because it also has some native code dependencies for OpenGL. You need to include these dependencies or the Java part of LWJGL won't work.

Options to consider:

- Explicitly **tell Java to load the native library** with something like "-Djava.library.path=..\libs\win32" as an option to java on the command line. You can probably also set up IntelliJ to do this for you. See http://lwjgl.org/installation.php .
- Use something like **Maven or Leiningen** to handle the dependencies for you. [LWJGL is on Maven Central](http://blog.gemserk.com/2011/10/22/lwjgl-on-maven-central/) so it should be pretty easy to pull in. In the long run you will probably want to figure this out as it will save you a lot of time with more complex builds.
- **Use a library** that already bundles all the dependencies for you. [Penumbra](https://github.com/ztellman/penumbra) might be a good choice.